# Access a private virtual member-function through pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, virtual-functions

```
class foo{
   public:
   int n;
   private:
   virtual void sayHi(){
      cout<<"Hi there!";
   }

};
```

How do I get the address of sayHi()??

```
main(){
foo f;
typedef void(*fptr)();
fptr func = reinterpret_cast<fptr>((&f)[0]);
(*func)();
}
```

The code above didn't work.

I know that the first 8 bytes of "f" object is a pointer to a virtual table where it contains the pointers to the functions, I'm using 64-bits machine. I'm basically trying to call the sayHi() through its pointer rather than calling it directly from f, since sayHi() is private anyway! How would I do this? Am I apportioning it right??

Comment: Are we talking about standard C++, or C++ on your specific compiler, operating system and processor architecture?

Comment: I'm using 64 bits machine. But it's ok with the standard c++. Thanks!

Comment: @Noor Thabit: Er... Nothing like that can be done in "standard C++". Standard C++ does not even have a concept of "virtual table".

Comment: Maybe then I misunderstood what standard c++ means. I'm fine with whatever solution. I just want to understand the process of approaching it.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a [pointer to member](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)?

Comment: Is the intention to have a semicolon at the end of the class definition, or not? Be sure to post real code. Preferably complete.

Comment: @Noor Thabit: You cannot call a *member* function through an *ordinary* function pointer, unless you are trying to implement some deliberate hack. If you are trying to implement a hack, you have to explain better what hack that is.

Comment: @NoorThabit: As a member function, you can't "just call it" not through the pointer.  It has an implicit "this" parameter that will require a value at minimum (though you may be able to pass it `nullptr`).  But as immibis says, as a member, you need a pointer-to-member.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks, I just forgot to put it.

Comment: Thank you all for the comment. I'm just trying to acces a private member function with freinding.

Comment: @AnT I'm not sure if its considered hack. Is there a specific member-function pointer?

Comment: @MooingDuck Ok, how do I approach it then?

Comment: @NoorThabit **with** friending or without? That is a very different question. With a specific [answer](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)

Comment: @RyanHaining No friending, the function is private!

Comment: @NoorThabit then you'll have to use that template runaround I linked in the previous comment. Your question here has a completely different title from what you are actually asking though.

Comment: @NoorThabit also [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Is your question just "how can I call a private member function from a non-friend?" Do you need to be using any kind of extra pointers here at all?

Comment: @RyanHaining Precisely, thank you! I want to use pointers only, no classes!

Comment: You clearly have to have a class in some way. It's getting increasingly confusing what you're asking for.

Comment: @RyanHaining thanks again for the comments. I'm sorry If I'm making you confused!

Comment: @RyanHaining Ok, basically how do can I get the address of sayHi() function while it's private, no friending, no new classes other than foo??

Comment: Without any other helper classes? impossible afaik. With some helpers: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

Comment: @RyanHaining Thanks! I checked that blog, and yeah the challenge is no new classes is allowed. The thing is that I can access a private variable member using pointer casting only, I figured that it would be the same for a function. And since it's a virtual function then all I need is the pointer to the virtual table which is an array of pointers to virtual functions. Normally the first 4 or 8 bytes of the address of a foo instance is the pointer to the vTable, once I access it then I should be able to access the function address!

Comment: @NoorThabit: In that case you need details about the version of your compiler.  Not all compilers generate virtual tables.

Comment: @NoorThabit: I just checked, you can't pass null as the 'this' parameter even if it's not used and even for nonvirtual functions. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e58b30a72d927c64

Comment: Wait, what challenge, where is this coming from?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you, but this challenge should be solvable, and again the virtual function has to be private. I'm using clang compiler.

Comment: @NoorThabit: No, the challenge is not solvable given that it's virtual, private, and you want no weird helper classes. C++ is explicitly designed to make this impossible.  Your only hope would be to not use C++, and use assembly or some other language to access the function.  In which case we'd also need the exact version of your CPU type you want to run this on, the exact compiler version, the details of the computer compiling on, and a bunch of other details that I don't even know about.

Comment: @NoorThabit Did you find the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply have a pointer to a non-static member function and call it without an object. The most straight-forward way to interpret your question would be using a [pointer-to-member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) as in:

```
auto fptr = &foo::sayHi;
foo f;
(f.*fptr)();
```

Now, you say you want to call it without having to go through `f`. It's not clear exactly what this means. Using a lambda is probably good enough to create a callable that works as you want

```
auto func = [] { return foo{}.sayHi(); };
func(); // call
```

or using a specific object and capturing it by reference (shown) or by value

```
foo f;
auto func = [&f] { return f.sayHi(); };
func();
```

Comment: @NoorThabit: Why not?

Comment: May be because `sayHi` is private ! @MooingDuck

Answer (score 1):

`sayHi()` is a non-static method of a class.  You need to use a **pointer-to-method** instead of a raw pointer (the implementation of a method pointer is compiler-specific, so assuming the internal layout of the pointer-to-method is not portable).

Also, `sayHi()` is *private* to `foo`, so `main()` cannot access it directly.  You need to either:

1. declare `sayHi()` as *public*:

   ```
   class foo
   {
      int n;
   public:
      virtual void sayHi(){
         cout << "Hi there!";
      }
   };

   int main()
   {
       typedef void (foo::*fptr)();
       fptr func = &foo::sayHi;
       foo f;
       (f.*func)();
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. make `main()` be a `friend` of `foo`:

   ```
   class foo
   {
      int n;
      virtual void sayHi(){
         cout << "Hi there!";
      }
      friend int main();
   };

   int main()
   {
       typedef void (foo::*fptr)();
       fptr func = &foo::sayHi;
       foo f;
       (f.*func)();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But sayHi() is private!

Comment: @EissaN.: the code compiles fine for me, provided that `sayHi()` is declared as `public`, or if `main()` is declared as a `friend` of `foo`, otherwise `main()` cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function. However, you can do something like this, if it helps. You may check the result [here](http://ideone.com/FPgTHM).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo{
   int n;
public:
   virtual void sayHi(){
      cout<<"Hi there!";
   }
};

typedef void(*fptr)();

int main() {
    auto func = reinterpret_cast<fptr>(&foo::sayHi);
    (*func)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not portable code, and not likely to work at runtime.  You are assigning a pointer-to-method to a raw pointer, using a type-cast to prevent the compiler from complaining about something that is potentially illegal and dangerous. And you still can't *call* a non-static class method using a raw pointer, the call stack will not be setup correctly.

Comment: Thank for the comment! Your solution works! However, the function has to be private!